# How to change Mac OS X look and feel

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors

After I attach and remove a secondary monitor on my Mac laptop my display changes to as shown below:
[image]

but this is how the screen originally looks (before connecting a secondary monitor):
[image]

Once I restart my machine the display corrects itself and I get the original look.

But I liked the blurred version ;) and I want it to stay permanent. How do I do that.

Comment: Enabling/Disabling LCD font smoothing doesn't help. The images you see above are screen grabs of a webpage displayed on the mac laptop.

Comment: The first pic makes me want to go get my eyes tested ;)

Comment: Ya I know. But I liked the first one.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?